# Detect Number overflow in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any builtin function in javascript which will notify, overflow of arithmetic operation on number data type?
Like c# and Java have.

Comment: C# is irrelevant tag for this question, hence removed

Comment: `if (BigInt(result) > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)` will tell you if it's greater than the largest `Number` JS can represent/store

Comment: also: Java is not Javascript. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jack `BigInt` is an unneccessary typeconversion there.

Comment: Which arithmetic overflow? Integer overflow? Number overflow? Invalid operations?

Comment: let notSafe = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === result;
if notSsafe is true then result is overflowed.

Comment: @AZ_ no, it does not

Comment: @JonasWilms any reason or explanation would help me to understand.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: @AZ_ well your statement is correct, however that does not mean that every too big integer will equal MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, therefore `result` won't be true in a lot of cases. Numbers can be bigger than it.

Answer (score 4):

Check from this site : [isSafeInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

```js
var x = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1;
var y = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2;

    console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
    // expected output: 9007199254740991

    console.log(x);
    // expected output: 9007199254740992
    console.log(y);
    // expected output: 9007199254740992
    console.log(x === y);
    // expected output: true
    
function warn(a) {
  if (Number.isSafeInteger(a)) {
    return 'Precision safe.';
  }
  return 'Precision may be lost!';
}

    console.log(warn(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER));
    // expected output: "Precision safe."

    console.log(warn(x));
    // expected output: "Precision may be lost!"
    console.log(warn(y)); 
    // expected output: "Precision may be lost!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the languages you were referencing, JavaScript does not throw if an invalid math operation is done. Instead, it returns special number values to notify you (doing Math on them always results in that specific value again, so you can just check for them at the end of an arithmetic chain):

```
 NaN // Operation could not be done
 Infinity // Number was too large
 -Infinity // Number was too small
```

For all those three special cases you can use [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) to check against:

```
 // a = 1000, b = 1000, c = 1 -> Infinity
 // a = -1000, b = 1001, c = 1 -> -Infinity
 const a = 2, b = 51, c = 0; // divide by zero -> NaN
 const result = a ** b / c;
 if(!isFinite(result)) {
   console.log("invalid operation");
 }
```

Also be aware that JavaScript numbers are floating point, with a precise integer range between (-2 ** 53, 2 ** 53), every integer outside of that will lose accuracy. The same applies to any non integer arithmetic which is never accurate.

Comment: isn't it  (-2 ** 53, 2 ** 53)?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER#Description

Comment: @AZ_ indeed, should've checked that instead of trusting on my memory :)